# SSIS error with COZYROC SSIS+ SugarCRM Source and OLEDB destination

Tags: mysql, sql-server, soap, ssis, sugarcrm

I have read access to a SugarCRM/MySQL (community edition 6.5.2). I want to get some of the data via SSIS into a SQL Server database.  I'm using COZYROC's SugarCRM Connection Manager and COZYROC's SugarCRM Source.

The interesting thing is that the table is created in SQLServer but the data does not come over.  The error seems to boil down to

```
   Error: 0xC002F304 at Data Flow Task, SugarCRM Source [240]: An error occurred   with the following error message: "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Access Denied
```

The full message is below.  I have tried working with COZYROC but they say that they cannot help because it's a problem on the server not the client.  I've tried posting to SugarCRM forums and SSIS forums but have received no responses.

It's critical that I get this to work so I'm hoping for help. Thanks. Also, I do not have access to the server so I cannot experiment by granting full access, testing, and, if successful, tightening privileges just to the point before it fails.  On the other hand, if someone can tell me specifically which privileges I might need, I can request them from the SugarCRM admin who is reluctant to provide additional access unless I can be specific about why I need it.

Here's the full message:

```
 SSIS package "C:\WCuto\SugarSkull\SugarSkull\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC002F304 at Data Flow Task, SugarCRM Source [240]: An error occurred with the following error message: "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Access Denied
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at CozyRoc.SugarCrm.Service.SugarCrmService.get_entry_list(String session, String module_name, String query, String order_by, Int32 offset, String[] select_fields, link_name_to_fields_array[] link_name_to_fields_array, Int32 max_results, Int32 deleted)
   at CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.SugarCrmSource._AddData(PipelineBufferWS outputBuf, Boolean deleted)
   at CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.SugarCrmSource.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)".
Error: 0x80004005 at Data Flow Task, SugarCRM Source [240]: Attempt to read message string for 0xc02090f5 failed with error 0xc02090f2. Make sure all message related files are registered.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on SugarCRM Source returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination 1" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\WCuto\SugarSkull\SugarSkull\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Comment: `Make sure all message related files are registered.` looks pretty dangerous to me. You've tagged mysql on this question. Are you hosting SugarCRM on a MySQL instance? MySQL is not a synonym for SQL Server

Comment: Also, could this be a permission issue? When you run the package, does it need to provide a different type of authentication?

Comment: I have SugarCRM with MySQL and a SQL Server destination database.  Thanks for your reply.  It was a permission issue in SugarCRM.  The admin opened it up a little more so I could run the SSIS package successfully.  I was about to update this thread.