# Sudden increase in packages failures executed against Sharepoint/Office 365 from SSIS

Tags: ssis, microsoft-graph-api

Beginning yesterday afternoon (12/9 Central US time) we began seeing a marked increase in SSIS packages execution failures. These packages have been in operation for several months and experienced no failures on 12/8.  Initially I brushed it off as temporary, but now it seems as if "none" of them are working.  Several of these packages run hourly, with the first failure around 10:30 on 12/9. Between 10:30 and 1500 'most' succeeded, but after 1500 on 12/9 most failed.

I'm testing with a relatively simple dataflow package.  I have two sources (SQL and Sharepoint). From the sources, I compare the two and then update the Sharepoint list with any changes that have been made (SQL query is the authoritative record). The Source Sharepoint list is the same list that is being updated.  As a further test, I removed all steps except for querying the Sharepoint list and sorting it. The initial query still fails.

Errors are happening inconsistently within the dataflow package. For example since I've been testing this morning, I had one (and only once) that made it through the package to the point it was should have tried to Add, Update or Delete list items. The table comparison resulted in updates to the Sharepoint list. The package failed when attempting to update the records. Most of them (and all recent attempts) are failing when the dataflow queries the Sharepoint list initially.  There are only two records on the Sharepoint List and two records on the SQL table.

I'm connecting to Sharepoint using MS Graph. Testing the connection (Connection Manager) within VS 2019 has succeeded every time. I've verified that the secret I'm using is not expired. I created a new secret and am receiving the same error. 'Usually' if I attempt to preview the Sharepoint source that is successful, but not always. Even if it is successful attempting to debug and run the package fails. I'm not seeing any alerts on Microsoft or Azure that would provide any indication that the problem's there, though I feel like something must have changed there.

I have opened a support ticket with CozyRoc and they have directed me to open a ticket with Microsoft. Microsoft's support request workflow is directing me here.

In the production All Execution reports, the error I'm getting back is:

"Data Flow Task:Error: Attempt to read message string for 0xc02090f5 failed with error 0xc02090f2. Make sure all message related files are registered."

Initial research pointed me toward a data typing issue, but I've not changed anything in our Sharepoint, SSIS or SQL environment to have changed the data types.

This appears to be very repeatable so I can try providing more information if needed.

Comment: "CozyRoc" and the error message are the most important things in this very wordy question. I suggest you take to most common failure and give some very detailed information about the issue. If you are using a CozyRock SSIS component and it's trivial to reproduce, and you are paying some kind of support then they need to help you fix it. But you need to create a trivial reproduction

Comment: Here's a similar question saying it was "permissions related" (very vague) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827999/ssis-error-with-cozyroc-ssis-sugarcrm-source-and-oledb-destination

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I had gone to CozyRoc initially, they sent me to Microsoft, Microsoft sent me here. My wordy description was an attempt to thoroughly describe the issue.
Below is the SSIS error message I receive in one of the packages. This step is trying to upload a CSV file to Sharepoint. StackOverflow isn't letting me put the full error message.
Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Jurassic.JavaScriptException:  Error: {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError":{"date":"**","request-id":"**","client-request-id":"**"}}}
LineNumber:0

Comment: Sounds like you're stuck between between vendors. If you can update a basic list fine manually, but can't do it using CozyRoc (using the same security credentials) then that seems like some thing you can take to CozyRoc. Having said that, the fact that it all started happening at the same time implies a change was made on the sharepoint side. Are you using your own Sharepoint or MS hosted SaaS sharepoint?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, It's on O365 sharepoint and the "account" that we're using via SSIS is an App Registration that we switched to as Microsoft turned off Basic authentication, so it's not quite the same authentication process. 
Ironically yesterday it seemed to work pretty well in the morning and as the day progressed it encountered more errors. I have not looked yet this morning to see how the overnight attempts did.

Comment: I ran the SSIS package locally with Fiddler and got a little more insight:
The first time I ran it, it ran successfully. I reran the exact same package (about a minute  or two later) and this time it failed while trying to update the Sharepoint list

The error Fiddler is showing that I got back is a 502 Bad Gateway: 

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"CH01EPF0000C550"}}

Comment: All I can say is intermittent bad gateway against O365 is definitely an MS thing, Perhaps you could raise a ticket with them wih that repro

Answer (score 0):

Look likes the answer was to wait. After about 1 week, the issue resolved as quickly as it appeared. I didn't find a way to report my issue directly to Microsoft without adding a support plan. I was in the process of finding alternative methods to address our needs when it resolved 'by itself'.